# How to dynamically generate json in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

The following class is just an entity for registration.

```
>   class registration
>     {
>     public string email
>             {
>                 get;
>                 set;
>             }
>             public string birthday
>             {
>                 get;
>                 set;
>             }
>             public string first_name
>             {
>                 get;
>                 set;
>             }
>     }
```

There is a signup method where i am processing the values which i got from the user.I have not included full code here.just give a brief information.I will process the fields and convert one json format.I will send the json input to webapi service for further process.

> class RegisterProcess { public void SignUp(registration regObj) {
>
> ```
>         JProperty UserProfile = new JProperty("RegisterProfile",
>                                new JObject(
>                                new JProperty("email", regObj.email),
>                                new JProperty("birthday", regObj.birthday),
>                                new JProperty("first_name", regObj.first_name))); } }
> ```

Some users might enter values for all fields & some of them will enter only for few fields.I want to insert only field which has a value.I want to dynamically generate JProperty UserProfile stuff.(for example:If an user enter only email&first_name,I want to create json only for those field.Null value should not be included.How to dynamically generate Json format.any ideas?

Scenario :: Registration entity - I will use for registration process as well as updateprofile process.During registration user might enter email,first_name,birthday.later he want to update only email field.He will enter data for that field alone.At that time i want to generate json rpoperty only for email field.it should not disturb[first_name and birthday] field.if i send [registration MyReg = new registration { email = "me@mail.com"};],It will set [first_name and birthday field] as null.It shouldn't set null for those fields.it should retain the value which i entered while registration.i hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the Newtonsoft JSON library installed:

```
registration MyReg = new registration { email = "me@mail.com", birthday="today", first_name="bob" };

String JsonReg = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyReg);
```

Isn't this all you need?  On the receiving end, missing (null) fields will just be skipped.

Comment: I will use the same entity while updating the user profile.so i don't enter the value in the email field while updating the profile,It should take the earlier one.I mean the data which i entered while registration.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Registration entity - I will use for registration process as well as updateprofile process.During registration user might enter email,first_name,birthday.later he want to update only email field.He will enter data for that field alone.At that time i want to generate json rpoperty only for email field.it should not disturb[first_name and birthday] field.if i send [registration MyReg = new registration { email = "me@mail.com"};]It will set [first_name and birthday field] as null.It shouldn't set null for those fields.it should retain the value which i entered while registration.i hope you got it